# Negative values in C# DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Is there a way to set negative values when calling the DateTime constructor.

like this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, 2, -1);
```

would be the same as:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 31);
```

I know this works in other languages, but the problem is that C# .net throws an exception when i'm doing this. Any ideas on how to do this in C# .net?

Comment: this can't work differently in different .net language, because `DateTime` is part of common library.

Comment: why do you want a negative date time? if you want to subtract time then either use .AddDays(-x) or .AddMonths(-x) etc or there is another class called TimeSpan which you can use for times that are not 1 whole day or 1 whole month etc.

Comment: @WraithNath: How am I supposed to write an app in .net to be reminded of the birthday of my dinosaurs with that limitation!?!?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. If you want to get the last day of the month, you should either start off with the start of the next month and then take off one day, or use [`DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx).

Personally I'd use the second approach, as otherwise you have to make sure you handle finding the last day in December correctly by starting off with January 1st of the next year, for example. Here's the code I'd use:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month));
```

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2011, 2,1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: I remember being confused to how you can add a minus day when I first started .net :P

Comment: @nik0lias: Hehe =) I have a background in mathematics, and would be confused if you couldn't add negative values!

Answer (score 1):

A [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) is always an absolute position in time. I think what you're searching for is a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx), which can also be negative.